# Select gets highlighted on clicking select label in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, select, dropdown

How to remove select highlight on clicking the select label in IE.
It is working fine in all other browsers.

```html
   <label class="fieldLabel specialinput" for="9d95e2bb-6b28-4153-96b5-9ebcd1937c44">Age</label>
<select name="9d95e2bb-6b28-4153-96b5-9ebcd1937c44" id="9d95e2bb-6b28-4153-96b5-9ebcd1937c44" data-val-required="Age" data-val="true">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="54">54</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgv8I.png)

Answer (score 0):

The highlighting of select will not occur by making label not clickable.

```css
label{
pointer-events:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the label's **for** property, like this:

```
<label class="fieldLabel specialinput" >Age</label>
<select name="9d95e2bb-6b28-4153-96b5-9ebcd1937c44" id="9d95e2bb-6b28-4153-96b5-9ebcd1937c44" data-val-required="Age" data-val="true">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="54">54</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```